# Create 'TABLE AS' in PL/SQL block

Tags: oracle, select, create-table

My query is simple but `PL/SQL` code block is expecting `'INTO'` statement.

Here is my query:

```
DECLARE

yesterdays_date DATE := SYSDATE-1;
start_date DATE :='01/JAN/2013';

BEGIN     
     EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'DROP TABLE P2P_DATA'; 
    EXCEPTION     
  WHEN OTHERS THEN         
   IF SQLCODE != -942 THEN     
 --if table not found DO NOTHING AND MOVE ON
 --dbms_output.put_line('HELLO');
            NULL;
    END IF;

---------------------------create new table here-------------------
CREATE TABLE P2P_DATA AS
SELECT 
    GM_NAME,
    NEW_SKILL,    
    WEEK_DATE,
    TOR_MWF
FROM TEST_TABLE 
WHERE WEEK_DATE BETWEEN start_date AND yesterdays_date;

END;
```

it gives the COMPILE time error:

```
FOUND CREATE: EXPECTING END SELECT or (BEGIN CASE CLOSE CONTINUE DECLARE ... ETC)
```

I am simply setting the dates in the declaration block and then creating a new table as a result of the `select` statement. any ideas how to accomplish this task?

Comment: you will have to use execute immediate to create the table as well as drop it.  Why not just truncate the table and then insert into it? This is not SQL server, dropping and creating tables has an overhead

Comment: @kevinsky any example code block will be appreciated

Comment: I'd just like to add, I wouldn't even consider a PL/SQL block for what you are doing there, you could issue a `WHENEVER SQLERROR CONTINUE` .. do the `DROP`, then issue a `WHENEVER SQLERROR EXIT sqlcode` ... and issue the `CREATE` .. with your date ranges (the variables here don't really help you much unless there's a lot more to this than you're showing ?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This does the same thing but avoids the execute immediate and overhead of creating and dropping tables.

```
DECLARE

yesterdays_date DATE := SYSDATE-1;
start_date DATE :='01/JAN/2013';

BEGIN     
 --clear out old data------
 DELETE from P2P_DATA;

---------------------------insert new data here-----------------
INSERT INTO P2P_DATA
SELECT 
GM_NAME,
CASE WHEN SUBSTR(CST_NAME,0,5) = 'A' 
     THEN 'BVG1' ELSE SUBSTR(CST_NAME,0,5) END AS CST_NAME,
NEW_SKILL,    
WEEK_DATE,
TOR_MWF,
TOR_MA,    
TOR_DL
FROM TEST_TABLE 
WHERE WEEK_DATE BETWEEN start_date AND yesterdays_date;

END;
```

--do your commit outside the transaction just in case

Even better just create a view and avoid the whole table thing when all you want is a subset.

```
CREATE VIEW VW_P2P_DATA 
AS
SELECT 
GM_NAME,
CASE WHEN SUBSTR(CST_NAME,0,5) = 'A' 
     THEN 'BVG1' ELSE SUBSTR(CST_NAME,0,5) END AS CST_NAME,
NEW_SKILL,    
WEEK_DATE,
TOR_MWF,
TOR_MA,    
TOR_DL
FROM TEST_TABLE 
WHERE WEEK_DATE BETWEEN TO_DATE('01/JAN/2013','DD/MON/YYYY') AND SYSDATE-1;
```

Comment: with no `WHERE` clause, consider `TRUNCATE` over `DELETE` ;) (hint: issue it just before the `DECLARE` outside of the pl/sql block ;) )  if that table is large, that `DELETE` could run a long time

Comment: @Ditto Sure DROP and TRUNCATE are DDL and cannot be done within a block without the execute immediate that I was trying to avoid.  Agreed that Truncate is cleaner and does not generate redo logs.

Answer (score 2):

You can not do DDL queries within a PL/SQL block; if you need to do so, you have to use dinamic SQL; for example, you could use:

```
execute immediate '
                    CREATE TABLE P2P_DATA AS
                    SELECT 
                        GM_NAME,
                        NEW_SKILL,    
                        WEEK_DATE,
                        TOR_MWF
                    FROM TEST_TABLE 
                    WHERE WEEK_DATE BETWEEN start_date AND yesterdays_date;
                    ';
```

However, please consider solutions different from create/drop tables on the fly if you can

Answer (score 1):

Actually, I'll put this as an answer instead of a comment ...

I'd recommend avoiding the PL/SQL entirely ... just do the following:

```
  truncate table P2P_DATA;

  insert into P2P_DATA
     SELECT 
      GM_NAME,
      NEW_SKILL,    
      WEEK_DATE,
      TOR_MWF
  FROM TEST_TABLE 
  WHERE WEEK_DATE BETWEEN to_date('01/JAN/2013','dd/MON/yyyy') AND SYSDATE-1;
```

Simpler, cleaner, and faster. ;)

Comment: but this can only be run as an SQL script.  I was assuming but it looks like this is something done more than once, perhaps even daily so wouldn't a procedure that could be called by a job be better?

Comment: @kevinsky: OP didn't mention anything about needing it in a procedure or such. And even that aside, this could be scheduled outside of a procedure, as a simple sql quite easily.  (if OP clarifies the need to change those input values - ie parameters - then yes, we have a completely different question) ;) lol